# reactjs: how to detect data changed and show notification

Tags: ajax, reactjs, notifications

hi guys im new in reactjs
i just want to know the react way, method/lifecycle that can render component (notification component) when ajax data result is different with previous state?

```
var NewsList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return ({
      data: [],
      showNotif: false,
      showLoading: false
    });
  },
  showNotification: function() {
    return (
      <Notification msg="new data" />
    );
  },
  ajaxRequest: function() {
  //do ajax request, load the result to this.state.data
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.setState({showLoading: true});
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.ajaxRequest();
    setInterval(this.ajaxRequest, 2000);
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.data != prevState.data) {
      //this.setState({showNotif: !this.state.showNotif});
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    var loadingElement, notifElement;
    if (this.state.showLoading) {
      loadingElement = <Loader />
    }
    if(this.state.showNotif) {
      notifElement = this.showNotification();
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {notifElement}
        {loadingElement}
        <NewsItem data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
});
```

so if you can see i expect the `ComponentDidUpdate` will read the changed state.data and if it's changed (meaning the ajax result has new updated), it will set `this.state.showNotif` to `true` and  render will call `showNotification()` but it's not (it's blinking, true-false set back and forth, so it's called many times)

what should i do to achieve it and make it right?

Comment: I think you should check if the new data is different *before* saving it to state, like `if (isDifferent(this.state.data, ajaxData)) { this.setState({ data: ajaxData, showNotif: true }) }`

Comment: great, i can see your point and somehow it's working. i dont know if this is a good practice or not, but thanks

Comment: `this.state.data != prevState.data` will always give you `true`.                               You need something like `_.isEqual()` from lodash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te best way to do this is updating data state only if is different then previous. For example:

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.ajaxRequest().done((data)=>{
       if(data !== this.state.data){
           this.setState({data: data, showNotif: true})
   })
```

But if you want to update state every time and check changes, the better place is componentWillReceiveProps:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.data != nextState.data) {
        this.setState({showNotif: true});
    }
}
```

The difference is that if you change data state, it cause component rendering and after that in componentDidUpdate, you render component second time (next setState). If you use componentWillReceiveProps - component render only one time.